# Calculate set bits in character

Tags: java, character, bit

So I saw this one question on the interwebs that was along the lines of

> Write a function that counts the number of bits in a character

Now obviously this confused me (or I wouldn't be here).

My very first thought was "aren't all `char`s 16 bits by default?" but obviously that has to be wrong because this question exists. I have no idea where to start. Maybe I can get the hex value of a char? Is there an easy way to convert from hex to binary or something? Is this something that can be asked about ANY language (I'm curious about Java here) or does it only matter to like C or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another approach if you want to avoid recursion.

```
public static int bitsSet(char arg) {
    int counter = 0;
    for (int oneBit = 1; oneBit <= 0x8000; oneBit <<= 1) {
        if ((arg & oneBit) > 0) {
            counter++;
        }
    }
    return counter;
}
```

**Update**

Here's a bit of an explanation.  In the loop, `oneBit` bit-shifts to the left each time, which doubles its value.  The `<<=` operation is a kind of shorthand for `oneBit = oneBit << 1`.  So, the first time through, we have `oneBit = 0000000000000001`.  Then the next time, we have `oneBit = 0000000000000010`, then `oneBit = 0000000000000100`, and so on, until we reach the last iteration, when we have `oneBit = 1000000000000000` (these are all binary of course).

Now, the value of `arg & oneBit` will equal `oneBit` if `arg` has the matching bit set, or `0` otherwise.  So the condition is executing `counter++` if it encounters a set bit.  By the time the loop has run all 16 times, we've counted all the set bits.

Comment: As per your other answer, you're right in thinking I'm looking for the set bits as that makes actual sense. A few questions (1) what is the `<<=` operator (never seen it before) and (2) can you explain what you're doing a little bit? Thanks!

Comment: haha well that makes sense. Great answer...this really helps understand bit logic. I'm surprised I couldn't find anything like it on the internet.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming from your title that you're after the number of "set bits" (that is, bits that are equal to one).  You can do it like this.

```
public static int bitsSet(char arg) {
    return arg == 0 ? 0 : (arg & 1) + bitsSet((char)( arg >>> 1 ));
}
```

And yes, all `char`s in Java are 16 bits.

**Update**

Here's a bit of an explanation.  `(arg & 1)` will check the rightmost bit of `arg` and return 0 or 1 depending on whether it is clear or set.  So we want to take that 0 or 1, and add it to the number of set bits among the leftmost 15 bits.  So to work that out, we shift `arg` to the right, introducing a zero at the left end.  We need `>>>` rather than `>>` to make sure that we get a zero at the left end.  Then we call `bitsSet` all over again, with the right-shifted value of `arg`.

But every time we do that, `arg` gets smaller, so eventually it's going to reach zero.  When that happens, no more bits are set, so we can return 0.

To see the recursion working, take, for example, `arg = '%' = 100101`.  Then we have the following - where all numbers shown are binary -

```
  bitsSet(100101) 
= (100101 & 1) + bitsSet(10010))  
= (100101 & 1) + (10010 & 1) + bitsSet(1001)  
= (100101 & 1) + (10010 & 1) + (1001 & 1) + bitsSet(100)  
= (100101 & 1) + (10010 & 1) + (1001 & 1) + (100 & 1) + bitsSet(10)  
= (100101 & 1) + (10010 & 1) + (1001 & 1) + (100 & 1) + (10 & 1) + bitsSet(1)  
= (100101 & 1) + (10010 & 1) + (1001 & 1) + (100 & 1) + (10 & 1) + (1 & 1) + bitsSet(0)
=       1      +      0      +     1      +     0     +    0     +    1    +     0
= 3
```

Answer (score 0):

All chars are 1-byte in C, Unicode (TCHAR) char's are 2 bytes.

To count the bits, you do bit shifting. I am not really that good at binary arithmetic personally.

Answer (score 0):

According to Oracle JAVA doc for primitives.

**char: The char data type is a single 16-bit Unicode character.**